# Rails4 scope OR condition with new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this working scope (I am using rails4):

```
scope :closed, where("state=? OR state=?", 'pending', 'complete')
```

But, rails complaints:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using #scope without passing a callable object is deprecated. For example `scope :red, where(color: 'red')` should be changed to `scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`. There are numerous gotchas in the former usage and it makes the implementation more complicated and buggy. (If you prefer, you can just define a class method named `self.red`.).
```

However, I cannot find a way to use the recomended syntax with a OR condition. Is there any way to do it elegantly, as the advise says?
Thanks

Comment: Answer is in the deprecation warning

Comment: The problem is using an OR with the suggestion syntax! And I was hoping to use state not inside a string... but I understand it is just a slight change in syntax.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting so may negative votes on this question... So, what I should read with: "There are numerous gotchas in the former usage and it makes the implementation more complicated and buggy." is that: If you put an arrow and some brackets, the implementation is less buggy... The idea must be bigger than that. I was expecting a more pretty solution, it is just it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the new syntax format we need to specify the lambda block symbole(->), so this older format will be removed in the future release. So you scope will become something like this,

```
scope, :closed, -> { where('state = ? OR state = ?', 'pending', 'complete') }
```

Comment: I was expecting something similar to this: scope :closed, -> { where(state: 'pending').or.where(state: 'complete') }     but I see I was complicating more, I accept your suggestion. thanks

Comment: You have an extraneous comma after scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply go with lambda:

```
scope :closed, -> { where('state = ? OR state = ?', 'pending', 'complete') }
```

Answer (score 0):

### scope(name, body, &block)

Adds a class method for retrieving and querying objects. A scope represents a narrowing of a database query.

```
scope :closed, -> { where('state = ? OR state = ?', 'pending', 'complete') }
```

for more information refer this **[Ruby Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)**